# Как найти слова из текста без String class методов?

Tags: java

С методами выглядит так:

```
String srt = "Hello world it is my first program ";
String aa[] = srt.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(aa[i]);
}
System.out.println();
char che = 'o';
String tar;
for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
    tar = aa[i];
    char[] oo = tar.toCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < oo.length; j++)
        if (oo[j] == che) {
            String y = aa[i];
            System.out.println(y);
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: т.е. разбить строку String по словам, без использования методов String?

Comment: пробегаетесь по строке....конкатенируя буквы. как только находите символ пробела - сконкатенированные буквы отправляете в массив, обнуляете переменную конкатенации и продолжаете дальше

Comment: я бы и этот код отрефакторил... зачем нужны переменные `tar oo y`. И если задача без методов из класса `String` то  например регуляркой `\\s[^\\s]*o[^\\s]*\\s`

Comment: Алексей Шиманский․․․символ пробел?, как

Comment: @ArtakKostanyan ну пробел это что? не слово же

Answer (score 2):

Не очень понял кусок кода с поиском слова с буквой "о" и как он относится к вашему вопросу, но если вам просто нужно разбить строку на слова, не используя `Split` (исходя из вашего вопроса, не смотря на ваш код), то вы можете воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
String s = "Hello world it is my first program";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

---

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по коду, я понял что ищется 1 слово содержащее букву `o`.

Comment: не одно а все, но без методов

Comment: @pavel да, ищется 1-е слово и стопарится, код никак не связан с вопросом, я вот этого не понял.

Comment: @ArtakKostanyan ваш вопрос - как разбить строку на слова без использования String class методов. Ответ приведен выше в моем коде - с использованием регулярных выражений.